# Can I modify VCS Operations quick list in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to add/remove some items from `VCS Operations` in Intellij IDEA, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can [create your own quick list](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-quick-lists.html) and assign the same shortcut to it instead of the VCS Operations.